# I'm having problems accessing a category from a question bank in Moodle

Tags: database, server, transactions, deadlock, moodle

I'm having problems accessing a category from a question bank in Moodle.

I'm using Moodle in version 4.0 and PHP in version 7.4.

When I try to access a category from a question bank in Moodle this error appears:

```
Error writing to database:

Debug information:  Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
DELETE FROM mdl_question_response_count WHERE analysisid IN (
SELECT id
FROM mdl_question_response_analysis
WHERE hashcode= ? AND whichtries = ? AND questionid = ?
)
\[array (
0 =\> '80ff80a084acf661db8978c57dabc0e88c0793f2',
1 =\> 'alltries',
2 =\> '7057133',
)\]
Error code: dmlwriteexception×Ignorar essa notificação
Rastreamento de pilha:
line 489 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: dml_write_exception thrown
line 291 of /lib/dml/moodle_read_slave_trait.php: call to moodle_database-\>query_end()
line 1686 of /lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php: call to mysqli_native_moodle_database-\>query_end()
line 216 of /question/classes/statistics/responses/analysis_for_question.php: call to mysqli_native_moodle_database-\>delete_records_select()
line 140 of /question/classes/statistics/responses/analyser.php: call to core_question\\statistics\\responses\\analysis_for_question-\>cache()
line 753 of /mod/quiz/report/statistics/report.php: call to core_question\\statistics\\responses\\analyser-\>calculate()
line 722 of /mod/quiz/report/statistics/report.php: call to quiz_statistics_report-\>analyse_responses_for_questions()
line 675 of /mod/quiz/report/statistics/report.php: call to quiz_statistics_report-\>analyse_responses_for_all_questions_and_subquestions()
line 950 of /mod/quiz/report/statistics/report.php: call to quiz_statistics_report-\>get_all_stats_and_analysis()
line 2492 of /mod/quiz/lib.php: call to quiz_statistics_report-\>calculate_questions_stats_for_question_bank()
line 8053 of /lib/moodlelib.php: call to mod_quiz_calculate_question_stats()
line 149 of /question/classes/local/statistics/statistics_bulk_loader.php: call to component_callback()
line 65 of /question/classes/local/statistics/statistics_bulk_loader.php: call to core_question\\local\\statistics\\statistics_bulk_loader::load_statistics_for_place()
line 1037 of /question/classes/local/bank/view.php: call to core_question\\local\\statistics\\statistics_bulk_loader::load_aggregate_statistics()
line 984 of /question/classes/local/bank/view.php: call to core_question\\local\\bank\\view-\>load_required_statistics()
line 768 of /question/classes/local/bank/view.php: call to core_question\\local\\bank\\view-\>display_question_list()
line 59 of /question/edit.php: call to core_question\\local\\bank\\view-\>display()
```

I've already tried restarting the server (linux) and the database, I've also tried updating the linux server.

I cleared the cache and localcache in moodledata, but it didn't solve the problem.

In my localhost test Moodle, I copied the database and it worked correctly, but in the production Moodle it continues to give the error. In other words, it's probably not a problem with the database, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was fixed in Moodle 4.0.8 by MDL-75576

The code has been removed

https://github.com/moodle/moodle/commit/118d3e855a3755a7c24c2927652101c853ead85b

You probably need to upgrade, the latest version is Moodle 4.0.11

Or try applying the commit

```
git show 118d3e855a3755a7c24c2927652101c853ead85b
```